# Solving a definite integral:

Tags: calculus

Let $f$ be given as $f(x) = | \sin x - \cos x | $. I want to find

$$ \int_0^{2 \pi } f $$

Can we use the fact that $ |a - b| \leq |a| + |b| $ ??

Comment: No. You should see when $\sin(x) > \cos(x)$ and when $\sin(x) < \cos(x)$

Comment: The inequality can't help since you're looking for an exact values of the integral (it would help if you were trying to bound the integral from above).

Comment: @Learner : If you use that, you'll get an inequality and not the integral itself. (unless R.H.S. becomes zero, of course!)

Comment: It could help if $\displaystyle \int \limits_{0}^{2\pi} |\sin|+\int \limits_{0}^{2\pi} |\cos|=0$, but this isn't the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

We know for real $a,$

$|a|=+a$ if $a\ge0,$ and for $a<0,|a|=-a$

Now, $$\sin x-\cos x=\sqrt2\sin\left(x-\frac\pi4\right)$$

In $[0,2\pi],$ $\displaystyle\sin\left(x-\frac\pi4\right)\ge0$ if $0\le x-\dfrac\pi4\le\pi\iff\dfrac\pi4\le x\le \pi+\dfrac\pi4$

Answer (score 1):

Hint. The function $g(x)=\sin x-\cos x$ is non-positive in $[0,\pi/4]$, and $[5\pi/4,2\pi]$ and
non-negative in $[\pi/4,5\pi/4]$. Hence
$$
\int_0^{2\pi} f(x)\,dx=-\int_0^{\pi/4}g(x)\,dx+\int_{\pi/4}^{5\pi/4}g(x)\,dx-\int_{5\pi/4}^{2\pi}g(x)\,dx.
$$

Comment: Is $g(\frac\pi3)>0$

Comment: I have fixed it!

Comment: What I should have pointed out is how have you identified the regions

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time, if you use inequalities to "compute" an expression, you'll get only a bound.

Take for example:

$$4+8\leq 10+10=20$$

but, of course, $4+8$ is not $20$...

To compute this integral, you must find the sets $I$ and $J$ in which $\sin x-\cos x$ is positive and negative, respectively. Then,

$$\int_0^{2\pi}|\sin x-\cos x|dx=\int_I(\sin x-\cos x)dx+\int_J(\cos x-\sin x)dx$$

To figure out what $I$ and $J$ are, just look at [this](http://www.geogebratube.org/student/m183407).